# Find TODO tags in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, todo

When I used Eclipse to add unimplemented methods to a Java class to fix an error, methods were auto-generated and include `// TODO Auto-generated method stub`

Is there an easy way to view all methods which contain this comment? Some sort of menu option?

Answer (score 398, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to view all methods which contain this comment? Some sort of menu option?

Yes, choose one of the following:

1. Go to *Window → Show View → Tasks* (**Not** *TaskList*). The new view will show up where the "Console" and "Problems" tabs are by default.
2. As mentioned elsewhere, you can see them next to the scroll bar as little blue rectangles if you have the source file in question open.
3. If you just want the `// TODO Auto-generated method stub` messages (rather than all `// TODO` messages) you should use the search function (Ctrl-F for ones in this file  *Search → Java Search → Search string* for the ability to specify this workspace, that file, this project, etc.)

Comment: I opened that window, and nothing shows. Any hints as to why this could be?

Comment: Yes. The project is open. All I see if the Find search bar, and an activate link. I was able to find the tasks under "Marker-> Java Task", but still no luck with that window.

Comment: The "Task List" tab is open, but it's not showing anything. I'll just use the markers for now, and troubleshoot later. Thank you.

Comment: but, but, "ignore the problem" goes against the code of the computer geek section 1.4.5.b-436

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31143/discussion-between-kprince36-and-andrew-w)

Comment: I encountered the same problem mentioned here.  The problem is that there are two view in the window menu, "Task List" and "Tasks".  TODO tasks show in the "Tasks" view, not the "Task List" view.

Comment: This shows the // TODO lines in ALL my projects. Any way you can limit it to just your current project?

Comment: @SnowCrash `View menu > Configure Contents > Show Items that match ..`

Comment: If the list is still empty, make sure to build or automatically build your project.

Answer (score 44):

Go TO Window>Show View >Markers

than you will get java task .

java task have all TODOs of your project

Comment: I found this to be the best answer. Actual Eclipse "Tasks" seem to be linked to an external system.

Answer (score 18):

*Tasks* view, under Window -> Show View -> Tasks

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes Window → Show View  does not show the Tasks. Just go to Window → Show View -> Others and type Tasks in the dialog box.

Answer (score 2):

In **adition** to the other answers mentioning the **Tasks view**:

It is also possible to filter the Tasks that are listed to only show the TODOs that contain the text `// TODO Auto-generated method stub`.

To achieve this you can click on the **Filters...** button in the top right of the **Tasks View** and define custom filters like this:

[image]

This way it's a bit easier and faster to find only some of the TODOs in the project in the **Tasks View**, and you don't have to search for the text in all files using the eclipse search tool (which can take quite some time).

Answer (score 0):

1. Push Ctrl+H
2. Got to File Search tab
3. Enter "// TODO Auto-generated method stub" in Containing Text field
4. Enter "*.java" in Filename patterns field
5. Select proper scope

Comment: Just curious, why is this answer downvoted so much? It solves the problem (altough not in the best way) and was posted at the same time as the accepted answer.

Comment: I think the reason is the answer was so obvious.

Comment: It is being downvoted so that it can be deleted.  It needs to be deleted because it is redundant.  We don't need multiple answers saying essentially the same thing.  And as you acknowledge, there are better ways to do this.