# How to jump to next TODO stub?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a hotkey in Eclipse which let me jump to the first TODO stub in the active tab?

I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Already answered e.g. in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903046/find-todo-tags-in-eclipse

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this is not the solution I search for. I would like to have a hotkey that moves my cursor immediatly to the first TODO stub in the active tab, without any steps in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for what look like up/down arrows in your editor's toolbar. They're for navigating to the next/previous Annotation, which in this context is the decoration of the text in the editor for an Error, Warning, Task, etc. You can customize which annotations they cycle through by dropping down their built-in menus, and then use them with whatever keybindings you have for **Next**/**Previous**. Odds are it will be Ctrl/Cmd+**.** .

Comment: Thank You, it helps. If I activate "Tasks" in the drop-down menu and disable other items, I can jump to the TODO stubs using (CTRL + ,) and (CTRL + .).

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can find it under following path,

```
Window -> Show View -> Tasks
```

Source : https://mcuoneclipse.com/2016/05/24/to-do-lists-with-eclipse-tasks-view/

Hot Key for this

```
Ctrl+H  : Search Workspace (Java Search, Task Search, and File Search)
```